# Apache 24 virtual host with document root on external drive

Tags: 16.04, apache2.4

#### Setup

- Ubuntu 16.04 on 256 gb ssd
- Windows 10 on 180 gb ssd
- Workspace on 1TB internal hdd
  on a machine. I choose Ubuntu or Windows during startup from the bios.

Workspace has a `www` folder where all my web development project folders are. It is set as the `DocumentRoot` for Apache 2.4 on Windows 10.

On Ubuntu `/home/me/www` folder have the exact same copies of all folders in the `Workspace/www`. Then I create symlinks of each folder to `/var/www/<corresponding folder>` and have Apache 24 `DocumentRoot` set to `/var/www` and each vhost is set with a `DocumentRoot` to a sub-folder in `/var/www` which is actually a symlink to the corresponding sub-folder in `/home/me/www`.

Everything is working .

#### Problem

I would like to share the same `Workspace/www` folder as the `DocumentRoot` for Apache24 in Ubuntu as well.
Workspace is being auto mounted as `/media/me/Workspace` with read write permissions for all i.e. owner, group and other.

However, when I try to setup a vhost with DocumentRoot as `/media/me/Workspace/www/project/public` it gives me a **403 Forbidden** error.
What am I missing? I have rechecked the file permissions for `Workspace` and confirmed that owner, group as well as other have read write permissions.

**Update**
After googling for hours and reading various solutions, I created an entry in `/etc/fstab` as under

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0832BD7832BD6AF8 /media/workspace ntfs-3g auto,defaults,permissions,users,x-gvfs-show,uid=me,gid=me,utf8 0 0
```

Now I have been able to remove the **403 Forbidden** error, but `npm run dev` is giving me an error ***Permission denied***.

If I try to change the permissions of for `node_modules` folder

```
chmod -R 777 node_modules  

sudo chmod -R 777 node_modules
```

there is no effect on the file and folder permissions - nothing gets changed.
I can't understand what is it that I'm missing or doing wrong.
The `Workspace` is formatted as **NTFS** as it is being used from Windows 10 as well. Could that be something which requires a different approach?
I also need to change permissions for certain folders such as ***storage*** and ***bootstrap/cache*** as  I work with **Laravel - php framework**.

Comment: Check permissions of parent folders. Each folder in path needs to have +x for other for apache to traverse it.

Comment: No the apache part is solved now. I am able to set the vhost DocumentRoot pointing to a folder in `Workspace/www` and can view the site in the browser. The problem is that the `node_modules` folder is giving me ***Permission denied*** . Although the `ls -l` shows the permissions as 777.  `npm install` runs fine but `npm run dev` or `npm run test` gives ***Permission denied*** error.